# jaxb: I use different method but all doesn't work

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jaxb2

I want to output a XML like this:

```xml
<master>
   <list type="array" nil="true">
<master>
```

I have tried `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement(nil=true)`, how should do this with jaxb.

```xml
<slave-status><connect-retry type="integer" nil="true"/>  
    <created_at type="datetime" nil="true"/>
<slave-status>
```

Comment: hello,@gabriel.do you have any idea

Comment: Why do you change the question after the answer? .. If is changed something you should open new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "master", propOrder = {
    "list"
})
public class Master {

    @XmlElement(name = "list")
    protected List list;


    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }


    public void setList(List value) {
        this.list = value;
    }

}
```

List.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "list")
public class List {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    protected String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "nil")
    protected boolean nil;

    public boolean isNil() {
        return nil;
    }

    public void setNil(boolean nil) {
        this.nil = nil;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

}
```

package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.ca.exporter.util;
```

Main.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jc =  JAXBContext.newInstance(Master.class);

        Master m = new Master();

        List l = new List();
        l.setType("array");
        l.setNil(true);

        m.setList(l);

        Marshaller mar = jc.createMarshaller();

        mar.marshal(m, System.out);


    }

}
```

Output - XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<master>
    <list type="array" nil="true"/>
</master>
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question can you remove xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" and  xsi:,i dont know how to do it

Comment: I updated the answer .. before i've used the nil concept of XSD schema, now is a simple attribute.

Comment: en..if write like mine,the (nil=true) just a Member variable,right? but if i use @XmlElement(nil=true),it is like this <delete_user xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>

Comment: In your case is an xml attribute, but could be an xml element too. In the other case is a xml nillable concept, [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp) .. Anyway.. accept the answer.